# Link parse error - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage where left part is index and right part is content. Now I would like to logout pill button on the left side but received error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: logout.php.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-sm-4">
  <li><a href="logout.php" data-toggle="pill">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's something happening that's not apparent from what you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have nothing like this (scroll animation):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```